What does の中で mean here?
明光の中で、この話題は美星に嫌がられてまでするものではないからだ。
The character 明光 had a talk with their friends and asked 美星 something. However, 美星 looked displeased and after that the character narration reflected on what happened.
Why is の中で used for a single person?
My reading is "Akari, on this subject, wouldn't not do to the point of getting hated by Sakura"

This question is similar to: の中では for emotions and thoughts?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
